# custom directive - Angular 2/4/5

Tags: angular, angular5, custom-directive

currently using angular 5 cli. 
i don't know why my custom directive not working. and not even showing error in my console. am trying to some style to maintain full image width.

so far.

```
import { Directive,ElementRef,Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[fullWidthImg]'
})
export class MyStyleDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer){
    renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement,'background-image', 'url("https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/full page/img(20).jpg")')
    renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement,'height', '100%")')
    renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement,'background-position', 'center')
    renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement,'background-repeat', 'no-repeat')
    renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement,' background-size','cover')
  }

}
```

copied from other resource

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ 
     selector: '[fullWidthImg]' 
})
export class MyStyleDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
       this.elRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/full page/img(20).jpg")';
       //this.elRef.nativeElement.style.fontSize = '20px';
    }       
}
```

### html

```
<div fullWidthImg></div>
```

where am doing wrong. if possible pls provide live example or good resource to understand custom directive

thank you

Comment: have you imported it import in app.module ?

Comment: yes i did in my app.module.ts

Comment: @worstCoder you should be set `height` and `width` to `div` tag otherwise should not display image

Comment: How much I should increase hight n width for width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this One:

```
<div fullWidthImg [ngStyle]="{'height': '200px', 'width':'200px'}"> </div>
```

Rest of code is working just change div tag only!!
Here is working example : [Image display](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4dmzt)

Answer (score 0):

How much I should increase for hight n width?